# Is $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be a linear topological space of all sequences
$x=(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n},\ldots)$ of real numbers with a product topology,
or, in other words, let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be a countable product of real lines.

Is $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}\setminus\{0\}$,
where $0=(0,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$?

If the answer is yes, how to prove this theorem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dear Natalia,  the first sentence  should be "Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be **THE** linear topological space of all sequences
$x=(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n},\ldots)$ of real numbers with **THE** product topology,
or, in other words, let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be **THE**  countable product of real lines." I know that in Russian (your native tongue?) there are no articles and it takes  some effort to use them correctly in English. But I am sure you will soon master them : good luck! (and +1 for your question)

Answer (score 17):

The answer is yes.

In Chapter VI § 2 of *Selected Topics in Infinite Dimensional Topology* (Bessaga & Pełczyński) is stated the surprising result that  $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, the Hilbert space $\ell_2$ and the unit sphere $S \subset\ell_2$ are homeomorphic spaces (${}^*\!$). The background required (developed in the previous chapters) seems to be rather wide. Anyway, proving this result, they exhibit an explicit homeomorphism between $S \smallsetminus \{\ast\}$ and $\ell_2$.

(${^*}\!$) moreover there is a 1966 paper by Bessaga entitled  *Every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is diffeomorphic with its unit sphere*

Comment: Another reference is R. D. Anderson's paper, *Topological properties of the Hilbert cube and the infinite product of open intervals* (1967).

Answer (score 7):

In "Infinite-dimensional Topology, Prerequisites and an introduction" by Jan van Mill ([table of contents](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2003;task=show_msg;msg=0806.0001.0001)) the author proves a characterization of $R^\infty$, also called $s$ in the book, which allows him to show that for any $\sigma$-compact subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ we have that $\mathbb{R}^\infty \setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. There is considerable machinery involved, but it's a very elegant exposition of these matters, IMHO. So the infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{R}$ behaves quite differently from its finite powers, in which homological/homotopical methods can be used to show e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{p\}$ are not homeomorphic.